# Trouble automating an import of functions from file to a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm attempting to import only global? functions from another file but two dictionaries do not return the same values.
I believe it is because the values_automated dictionary has string values but I"m not sure how to access the function address into a variable.

input

```
value_by_hand = {
    "function_1": function_1,
    "function_2": function_2

}

values_automated = {}
with open("file.py") as f:

    for text in f.readlines():
        if text[0] == "d":
            text = text.strip()
            texts = text.replace("def ", "")
            texts = texts.replace("():", "")
            values_automated[texts] = texts
    print(values_by_hand)
    print(values_automated)
```

Output:

```
{'function_1': <function function_1 at 0x101a1a110>, 'function_2': <function function_2 at 0x101a2a1b0>}
{'function_1': 'function_1', 'function_2': 'function_2'}
```

Comment: why do you want to parse this manually, since Python already does this for you? E.g. "from file import function_1"

Comment: and yes, you're right, the value_by_hand dict has of course function pointers, while the string parsed dict only contains strings. To turn these into function objects as well, you need to import them.

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-import/#modules

Comment: I tried to do it this way because "file.txt" has more than 2 functions. I'm trying to import them and put them into a dictionary so I can call them from a tkinter button. I wanted to do it this way so I dont have to keep importing new functions as I update the "file.txt"